# How to add timeline markers to HTML audio tag controls

Tags: html, css, html5-audio

Given an HTML audio element, how can markers be added to the controls playbar?

For example, say the track is 1 minute long, I want to be able to add a marker so the user can see that at seconds 4, 32, and 47 there is important information.
I'm open to external libraries if necessary, but pure HTML / CSS + javascript would be better.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please provide it.

Comment: No, I am looking for ideas on how to implement.

Comment: try this: https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/03/17/creating-video-player-with-time-markers

Comment: @A S how'd it go?

Comment: Will need some time before i can implement myself, but should work. Thanks again

Comment: worked well. thank you